# query inside of query

Tags: mysql, sql

Table questions has the question id and title.
Table posts has the id, question_id, post.

Is it possible to search for a field in a table using FULLTEXT indexing, and based on the rows  value of the question_id field for example, perform a count of posts which have that question id which is being retrieved by sql. JOINS isnt helping me at the moment i'm afraid.

I have discovered the answer, you can select the id AS RESULT_ID and then perform another query with that answer! Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548235/fulltext-search-not-returning-total-count

Comment: @yehuda That seems awfully like the same exact question as this one. You should *not* ask the same question twice.

Comment: @yehuda: from your question it sounds as you only have a single fulltext index on one of your tables, not on both.

Comment: @knittl I have indexes on both.

Comment: @Andrew The first question is how to solve my problem. Now I am asking of I want to solve it by getting the question_id, is this possible!

Comment: @Subail Cant see how that would help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first join things up.

```
select q.question_id, q.title
from question q, post p
where q.question_id = p.question_id
```

then filter down to the posts you want

```
select q.question_id, q.title
from question q, post p
where q.question_id = p.question_id
and p.post like '%SEARCHTERM%'
```

(or full text or whatever)

then count up

```
select q.question_id, q.title, count( post_id )
from question q, post p
where q.question_id = p.question_id
and p.post like '%SEARCHTERM%'
group by q.question_id, q.title
```

Comment: this is the thought progression.. the final statement is the result.

Comment: But i havent yet got an id to work it. I need some sort of SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE post_id = (RETRIVED DATA FROM EARLIER PART OF QUERY)

Comment: Thanks, it could be that is what you meant from the beginning